# How can i make my OS X application downloadable?

Tags: xcode

I want to download my Mac application from xCode so i can use it myself.
I have gone through all the tabs at the top of xCode but don't find annything.
How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your App is build, you can find it under `Products`. To find it:

- righ+click on the .app file
- choose `Show in Finder`

[image]